# Why does this tensorflow.keras code take huge amount of memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow2.x

I have the following code that takes 3GB physical RAM and 144GB virtual RAM:

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(input_shape,)))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[AUC(curve='PR', 
                                                        name='auc')])

es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_auc', patience=10, mode='max', verbose=1)

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=50, verbose=0, 
         validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[es], epochs=500)   
eval_auc = max(history.history['val_auc'])
ix=np.argmax(history.history['val_auc'])
print("Number of interations: ", ix)
print(eval_auc)
```

The X_train is of shape (44,000, 1,233) and its datatype is `np.int8`. It takes 52MB of memory space. I am using tensorflow V2.2. Why does it take so much space? What should I do to reduce the memory usage?

Comment: Hi ! could you give us a minimal reproducible example so that we can just copy-paste this code and see it at work. Even better if you put it in a shared google colab that we can directly use.

Comment: Yes, you can run the program in the "Overfit MLP With Early Stopping" section of this link: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-stop-training-deep-neural-networks-at-the-right-time-using-early-stopping/

Comment: On AWS EC2, it shows 140+GB of virtual memory used. On my MacPro, it shows over 100GB of virtual memory used. I use 'htop' to monitor the execution. You may want to increase the n_samples to a large number to observe it; e.g., from 100 to 1000. The physical RAM used is only 200MB.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. In the link you posted, they talk about 2D data when you mention 1233 dimensions.

Comment: The easiest would be if you I could just copy-paste some code that you have that gives the error you notice.

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi Please look at the code block above/before the 2D ata. You went pass the one I intended to show. Sorry for the delay. We had some fire hazard in the last two days from some arsonists to protest the unjust.

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi I did copy-paste some code in my original question. But you need data to run. So I posted a link that has code with data. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

By default, tensorflow pre-allocates nearly all of the available GPU memory, which is bad for a variety of use cases, especially production and memory profiling. When keras uses tensorflow for its back-end, it inherits this behavior. 
Tensorflow allows you to change how it allocates GPU memory, and to set a limit on how much GPU memory it is allowed to allocate.

```
## keras example imports
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import LSTM

## extra imports to set GPU options
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as k

###################################
# TensorFlow wizardry
config = tf.ConfigProto()

# Don't pre-allocate memory; allocate as-needed
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

# Only allow a total of half the GPU memory to be allocated
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.5

# Create a session with the above options specified.
k.tensorflow_backend.set_session(tf.Session(config=config))
###################################

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_features, output_dim=256))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=10)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=16)
```

To reduce the memory associated further, you can create a Sparse Matrix from a Dense (full) Matrix.

Comment: The problem exists without using GPU. Also, please comment based on tensorflow V2.x and tf.keras. Thank you.

Comment: I guess the easiest way to sidestep the batch optimization is simply not specifying an input layer in the model

Answer (score 0):

52MB per image = 52000000 * 50 = 2600MB per batch

> model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))

weights: 50 * 52MB * 4 = 10400MB (each output * each input * 4 bytes, I assume float32 weights. Actually, it needs 50x4 bytes for the layer values but who cares for a few bytes)

> model.add(Dropout(0.1))

1040MB

> model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

1040MB

Total memory: 2600 + 10400 + 1040 + 1040 = 15080MB = 14.7GB

- Are you sure that you are using int8? Keras backend usually use float32 or float64, lower precision can cause accuracy problems.
  If the backend uses float32, then each image uses 208MB of memory, a batch of 50 images use 10400MB instead of 2600MB.
- Are you sure that your image has only one color channel? If it is loaded as RBG then you need three times more RAM for image.
- Do your code loads other data? Minimize the code footprint to the minimum required for the training and see if you still need the same amount of memory.